# Classify and create Intention list from a MongoDB Conversation List

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, tensorflow, deep-learning

I want some tips and advice about get a conversation list inside mongoDB and create Intention from it to use in chat-bot.
ex:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectID("5a908f07309a76002be10175"),
    "chatid": "S1xp$kGRvf",
    "sequencial": null,
    "user": "S1xp$kGRvf",
    "msg": "oi",
    "time": 1519423239675,
    "datahora": "2018-02-23T19:00:39.675Z",
    "ambiente": "prd"
}
```

Using tensorflow and DNN tools.

Answer (score 0):

Find the answer by using Word count, word to vector, and DNN in Word to vector to generate step by step!